# NavigableSet with own object types?

Tags: java, collections

How can I use `tailSet()` and `headSet()` for a `NavigableSet<MyType>`? And also implement own rules which elements would qualify for a tailset or headset?

Like:

```
class MyType {
  String name;
  String number;
}
```

Now if I have a type("daniel", "12"), I want to have all elements which are alphabetically before daniel, and number > 12. This would be my headset. The opposite would be the tailset.
(of course the comparisions do not make any sense, but you get what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either let `MyType` implement `Comparable` or use a `NavigableSet` which let you provide a separate `Comparator` like `TreeSet`.

Comment: That said, you _must_ have it be a "total ordering" -- you can't do the queries you're trying to describe for elements before "daniel" and numbers greater than 12 without building your own custom data structure.